# C# Poker Libraries

Tags: c#, poker

I'm building a simple poker website for a demo. Anyone know where I can find a set of classes encapsulating card, deck, hand etc. ?

Google is not being very helpful, (most links are to codeproject which is down until 1pm EST - I'm in Ireland).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeproject is currently down for me too, but in my implementation of Texas Hold'em I used [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/pokerhandevaldoc.aspx) for representing the hands, as well as evaluating which player has the best hand (a pretty tricky task). It worked out great for me.

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll just wait till it comes back up and take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of a C# library I am working on:

https://github.com/NikolayIT/TexasHoldemGameEngine

It contains all you need: Cards, Deck, Shuffle, Hand, Players, Game Engine, Hand Evaluation and Unit Tests.